# entity framework How to update all entities with the same value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a scenario where all users have a a property that can take true or false and I'm looking for the least painful way to update this property for all users, right now I'm loading all users + using foreach to loop and update the property + then save changes to the database, but you can imagine how late it would be when the number of users is very very large, also this property may need to be updated many times a day --not by admin only-- so I need it to be fast.

Can someone tell me a better way to do it ?

Note: I didn't test that yet -of course - with large number of users, so If you have experience with situations like this and you think that wouldn't take long, please let me know
Thanks

Comment: You should provide more info about the property. It could be calculated, computed nightly, ...

Comment: okay ... this property is used to notify the user with new event, it's called ShouldNotify and It need to be set to false once the user requested the actions that return this property, so I can get the number of user who have seen the updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something like this, it should be only 1 update query to your DB.

```
context.Users.Update(x = > New Users(){ MyProperty = true});
```

You can see more information here:

http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2015/01/26/performing-bulk-updates-entity-framework-6.1%2B

Comment: what is "NorthwindContext" ? does it has a nuget package?

Comment: That's not important. The point is: use [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended).